# Sitecore adding extra title to header

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I am an asp.net developer working on a sitecore based site, our sitecore expert is on holiday at the moment and sitecore seems to be doing something that I don't understand.

I need to dynamically add meta tags to the page header so I added runat="server to the head tag as below

```
<head runat="server">
```

This works and allows me to do what I need to do, however there is a strange side effect, it adds an empty `<title></title>` tag to the header and I can't work out how and why this is happening. We currently have a site wide static title so we end up 2 title tags which is annoying.  However we intend to start setting the page title dynamically soon so guess I want to know 2 things?

Why/how is is this happening?

Is it something that can easily be hooked into to set the page title dynamically based on the value of a sitecore field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I know it's a known asp.net issue (feature?).
You can add a hidden title tag runat server to the head, to avoid creating additional empty title tag, e.g.:

```
<title visible="false" runat="server"><%-- I'm necessary here, do not remove me --%></title>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to do it in a vanilla asp.net site but in the sitecore site the title was in a user control so maybe that is the difference.

Comment: Yeah, it would behave in the same way if you have a placeholder on your master page and then add title tag from your aspx pages.

Comment: thank you. This was an odd issue, thanks for the fix, worked like a charm.